# How to change part of HTML 'form action: link' elements using Java script or html ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a link to a database in the server and I'm using an HTML form where the action points to the link and GET the information from the server.

I need to change the 'username' part of the link so that it takes in the username i enter and uses it in the link.
What's the best way to achieve something like this?

```
<body>

        <form id = "me" action= "http://10.10.10.10/foods/<username>/" target="_blank"  method="GET">
            <h2>Enter Username</h2>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="username" id = "user" >
                <br>
            <button class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" >get</button>
        </form>
        <script>
          var username = //need to get input username;
           document.getElementById('me').action = "http://10.10.10.10/foods/" + username + "/";
</script>
</BODY>
```

this is all i have so far and i am stuck

Comment: Is there any spesific reason to make the input as part of the URL rather than taking the username value from the GET query?

Comment: what do u want change form action by js or enter username in from action 
also do u have username in your view if yes then in which lang js or php

Answer (score 3):

Do this simple submit event

```
 $('#me').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();//prevent the submit
  var username = $(this).find('#user').val();//take the username
  window.location = "http://10.10.10.10/foods/" + username + "/";//redirect to the page
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just redirect the user to the page and disregard any data that should be carried in the GET query?

Comment: @Pratansyah the data carried in the GET query is only the username which he already has in the url so its not necessary , he could remove the form entirely and have only a click event

Comment: I was assuming it was a simplified form but if that's all the form is then better include that comment in your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var username = document.getElementById("me").action;
    var updatedStr = username.replace("<username>", "action name");
    document.getElementById("myForm").action = updatedStr;
</script>
```

Comment: Try adding comments in your answer and explain things. Simple code will not help others.

Comment: Get Lost @SaqibOmer

Comment: Welcome @user5632900. Let me know in case of any concerns!